# Asynchronous Mapreduce - how to execute reducer function before completion of all mapper task?

Tags: java, hadoop, asynchronous, mapreduce

I am trying to implement asynchronous mapreduce code for one of the machine learning algorithm. But I am stuck at how i can invoke reducer function just after say 3 out of 10 mapper task completes and perform the functionality on these 3 mapper outputs. I took reference from this research paper [Enhancing Mapreduce via Asynchronous Data Processing by Marwa Elteir](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwichd-y77vQAhVBPo8KHYbtA1EQFggiMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpeople.cs.vt.edu%2F~feng%2Fpubs%2Fpapers%2Fmarwa-icpads10-mapreduce.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGLcoseBp5jx92uWw--llbslGhopg&sig2=hIAlrjS_eVxMZzvU3Ie8Jg)

Comment: The reducers can't start until all the mappers have finished.

Comment: @BinaryNerd actually with asynchronous data processing it is possible. I am taking refernce from research paper.